# Does JavaFX have examples of popular apps?

Tags: java, javafx, production

JavaFX has been released a long time ago. But I didn't hear about any popular or big production ready projects built with this technology.

Comment: It is good question for desktop app developers. I have been using JavaFX over two years now. Revolutionary? Yes. Much more intuitive, organized, capable and scalable than Swing could ever be. A scenegraph based layout is logical. The binding and henceforth expressiveness of code coupled with lambda is amazing. That said, this is what upsets me: put the keyword *javafx* and compare it with *swing* in dice.com for example, see the difference! It amazes me that such a powerful framework that is probably the de facto to implementing desktop apps has this puny popularity in the jobmarket. Comments?

Comment: I don't see why such a question be put on hold. A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318645/javafx-or-swing) on this topic was asked years ago.To get a feel of how the technology we are using is doing to decide whether it is worth it to invest time and effort learning, answers, however they come, would be eye openers and help the perplexed make a decision early on. It is not like a *Java or .NET* where worlds collide indeed, it is a *where is this technology heading, or who's using it?*, which I think are questions worth asking and answering.

Comment: I can imagine GUI for lot of trading apps at investment banks being written in JavaFX instead of bloaty Chromium/JS based eco-system. Yes there's a trade off of _look-and-feel_ but the very nature of such financial apps do not demand too much in aesthetics.

Answer (score 5):

*Opening the answer to everyone...*

Though this question is `primarily opinion-based`, but I would still like to throw some examples. These may not be very popular, but are good enough to be used by a few people:

1. [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)
2. [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/Developers-Corner/technical-overview.html)
3. [VRL Studio](http://vrl-studio.mihosoft.eu/)

Comment: the next example is rapid miner studio.